# Is there a way to set the IDE to default to the Windows 64-bit platform for newly created project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-ide

In Embarcadero Delphi 11, when creating a new VCL project, the `Target Platform` is by default set to Windows 32-bit. For ease of access, I would like to be able to make new projects default to Windows 64-bit.

With most installations of Windows being 32-bit apps, and the release of Windows 11 no longer supporting a 32-bit variant, compatibility is no longer an issue for most devices. 32-bit apps also have their own version of the Windows registry.

While switching the platform doesn't take long, it's not ideal. And I assume the default project file is not hard-coded in the IDE, so there must be a way to change its settings.

I tried to search in the `%PUBLIC%\Documents\Embarcadero` folder for any files that could be the default project. I also attempted to search the IDE for any settings talking of a default project. The only settings called `Default Project`, refers to the default folder in which a new project is created.

Comment: "32-Bit apps also have their own version of the Windows registry and can't handle Int64 values." 32-bit applications can handle 64-bit integers just fine. (But *pointers* are restricted to 32-bit integers.)

Comment: IIRC, this is not possible, but there is a feature request to make it possible.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Could you please provide a link to the feature request page if you have It?

Comment: I just had a quick look in the Embarcadero Jira, but didn't find it. (I don't like the Jira search feature.) I'm a bit occupied right now, so I'll search more later today.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Alright, thank you. I will have a look myself to see If I can find It. If you stumble upon It later, please tell me.

Comment: Ah, here it is: [RSP-39042](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39042)

Comment: If you no longer plan to build 32 bit apps you could remove that platform

Comment: @KeithMiller, as the platform selection only allows Windows, macOS, Linux, iOS and Android I wonder how you would do that.

Comment: How often do you make new projects?

Comment: @UweRaabe Not sure, the target platform on my Delphi only shows Windows 64 Bit

Comment: @KeithMiller What is your Delphi version? Older ones allow to select individual platforms, while newer ones only offer groups.

Comment: @UweRaabe Delphi 11 Version 28.0.44500.8973

Comment: @KeithMiller Strange, I am not aware of any official way to remove individual platforms from the IDE - only from projects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Pretty often actually. Sometimes I can create up to 2 projects/a week. Most of them are just small utilities.

Comment: I don't really see the benefit but if you want to do this, create a tool to generate new projects with the appropriate settings. Or use ahk to automate the ide to do the same.